# Convert NSExpression to MGLStyleValue<>

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I try to do:

```
var cards = [MGLPolygonFeature]()
for card in cardsArray {
    let polygon = MGLPolygonFeature(coordinates: &coordinates, count: UInt(coordinates.count))
    polygon.attributes = ["name": card.name]

    cards.append(polygon)
}

let cardSource = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "cards", features: cards, options: [:])
mapView.style?.addSource(cardSource)

let labelLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "card-labels", source: cardSource)
labelLayer.text = NSExpression(format: "CAST(address, 'NSString')")
labelLayer.textOpacity = 
    NSExpression(format: "mgl_interpolate:withCurveType:parameters:stops:($zoomLevel, 'linear', nil, %@)", [16: 0, 17: 1])
```

But it doesn't work because of errors:

> Cannot assign value of type NSExpression to type MGLStyleValue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use an NSExpression with a 3.x version of the Maps SDK. In that case, you will want to use a `MGLStyleValue`.
You may want to try something like:

```
 let stops = [16: MGLStyleValue(rawValue: 0),
              17: MGLStyleValue(rawValue: 1)
 ]
 labelLayer.textOpacity = MGLStyleValue(interpolationMode: .exponential,
        cameraStops: stops,
        options: nil)
```

You can find pre-v4.x sample code for setting a layer's opacity [here](https://github.com/mapbox/ios-sdk-examples/blob/4e490d9eee10d4bd8673f881eb271dcc3a309b68/Examples/Swift/WebAPIDataExample.swift#L64-L67). You may also find the [v3.7.8 documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.8/Classes/MGLCameraStyleFunction.html) helpful.

Comment: what about layer text?

Comment: I need to assign as a text name attribute for every card from cardSource

Comment: Something like `labelLayer.text = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: "{name}")` ([example](https://github.com/mapbox/ios-sdk-examples/blob/4e490d9eee10d4bd8673f881eb271dcc3a309b68/Examples/Swift/WebAPIDataExample.swift#L71))   should work for your use case. Replace `name` with the key for the name, but keep it within the curly brackets. Those are used for string interpolation for the SDK pre-v4.0.0.